# Plotly truncating data values outside y axis range

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

Is there a way to get Plotly not to truncate data labels?  In the example below, the data values for the topmost series are getting truncated.  If I explicitly set `"yaxis":  { "range": [0,1.1] }}` it shows correctly but I'm hoping that this can work with autorange

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/__proto__/pen/KKRGroa)

Here the layout includes:

```
{
  "yaxis": {
      "autorange": true,
      "automargin": true, 
      "tickformat": "0%",
       "type": "linear"
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, mostly.  This was a toy example but our production example has the same issue.  Even if the margins are zero, if the graph outer boundary size is too smal; then the data labels for the topmost series which get rendered outside the bars also can get squeezed outside the chart.  I think Plotly has some heuristic for sizing that gap above but there is no way to ensure it is always enough. So for now the answer for us is "make the graph bigger".

Answer (score 1):

You use very large values for margins, which reduce the space of the plot and leads to the truncation. You should change the margins to the following values:

```
"margin": {
    "l": 60,
    "r": 20,
    "t": 10,
    "b": 50
},
```

[image]